# SQL UPDATE with JOIN

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sql, join

Knowing I want Magento assemble and execute the following query :

```
UPDATE
    `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `tGV`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `tG` ON
    `tG` . value_id = value_id
SET
    `tGV` . `position` = 2
WHERE
    (
        `tG` . `value` LIKE '%_pms_%'
    )
```

I came to the following code :

```
$select = $connection
    ->select()
    ->join(
        ['tG' => $tableGallery],
        '`tG`.`value_id` = `tGV`.`value_id`',
        ['position' => new Expr('2')]
    )
    ->where("`tG`.`value` LIKE '%_pms_master%'");

$update = $connection->updateFromSelect($select, ['tGV' => $tableGalleryValue]);

$connection->query($update);
```

This code works but it is not obvious to understand and therefore to maintain. Question is : do you have any idea how to do better : simpler / cleaner / more understandable ?

Comment: `$update` is a string that is the SQL statement. I would just `echo $update` and copy the output as comment.